# Continue to increment formula by x columns across columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet 1 contains all the raw data, and Sheet 2 contains the summary of the data in Sheet1.

In Sheet2, I am trying to use =SUM to find the sum of every 7 cells horizontally, and drags it horizontally to automatically increment select the next set of 7 values.

| B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =sum(Sheet1!B2:H2) | =sum(Sheet1!I2:O2) | =sum(Sheet1!P2:V2) |

Here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EQBiUUV3EA69gwePA2DLr8gQMIZvGeNAu478RktwF6c/edit?usp=sharing

I tried doing a couple cells manually and dragging the formula horizontally, but it does not work. I was expecting the columns to automatically increment when I drag the formula to the next column.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(Sheet1!2:2,weeknum(Sheet1!1:1,2)=weeknum(B1,2))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more literal solution:

```cpp
=LET(rng,Sheet1!B2:2,
     n,7,
     MAP(
       SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(rng)/n,1,n),
       LAMBDA(i,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(rng,SEQUENCE(1,n,i))))))
```

This formula generates a list of the starting indexes using `SEQUENCE` then it uses `MAP` to iterate over each of them while picking and summing the next `n` values in the range using `CHOOSECOLS` and `SUM` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Also (a simple one)

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!2:2,Sheet1!1:1,">="&B1-6,Sheet1!1:1,"<="&B1)
```

[image]